# Deploying python on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

I have a python file running locally and it uses files stored locally. I want to upload everything to google appengine and run it from there. i have been able to upload and run helloworld type of programs, but i am not able to upload and deploy a complex program which uses data from csv files.

Is it possible to upload the program and the csv files to google appengine and have the whole thing run there?

i was not able to find any documentation related to this on google appengine etc. please help or refer me to a simple tutorial...

thanks,

RS

Answer (score 1):

Just deploy the csv file with the code.  Make sure you do not put it in a directory served by a static handler.  csv file will be readonly and as long as thats all you need you will be fine.

There is no specific documentation on this as other than the read only restriction you are dealing with standard python.

Comment: so there is no way to write to a filesystem? Is there any workaround?

Comment: No.  Write to the datastore or gooogle cloud store.  Oh and the read the docs, this is all clearly stated

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.

Are you expecting people to guess at what went wrong?  If I have to guess, the answer is usually "you haven't read the docs".

You probably should read up carefully on the filesystem and static files.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/staticfiles?hl=en

I'd guess that you're either trying to write to the filesystem, which is not allowed, or you're trying to read a file that's put on a static handler, which is inaccessible.

Or you did something dumb, but it would be hard to guess at that without any error message.

Comment: so there is no way to write to a filesystem? Is there any workaround?